# Form Post and sort links

Tags: php, html

I have a form that submits with POST
For the user to sort the results, there are a few links.

But if I use classic link I will lose the POST info from the previous search
What would be the best way to handle this?

Thx
Chris

Comment: if you share some code you will get more assistance - the more the better (HTML / PHP / Javascript)

Comment: You could use javascript to send post data when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the POST'ed info in `$_SESSION`, and use that to remember search settings when you sort them.

Alternatively, you could use pure client-side javascript to sort the results in-browser.

If it's publicly viewable, and the form submit doesn't change any data, I'd suggest you use GET instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's tough to say. It sounds like users enter a search term and are brought to a page where they can reorder the results. The reordering is done via post and you want to then return the user back to their search result page when complete. Is this correct?

You could include the search term in the posted data, then redirect to that search when the server is done processing the post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you maybe interested in using `GET` as the form method and [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to get the search term.

You can then use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to build the links in your search results so that the terms are not lost.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly less orthodox solution: instead of links, use `<input type="submit">` buttons and style them to look like hyperlinks. Give them a class and style them for the screen using CSS. You will be able to track which order you want by checking $_POST for the names on your linky buttons. I've used this technique many times and as far as I can tell nobody has ever had a problem with it.